# My Scala Installation seems to be very slow, is there a reason for this?

Tags: performance, scala, cygwin

I am using Scala version 2.11.8 on my laptop running Windows 10 and Cygwin. This is the output of running a compiled hello world script in Scala:

```
$ time scala hello
Hello World

real    0m2.405s
user    0m0.241s
sys     0m0.548s
```

This seems excessively slow compared to almost every other programming language especially considering that the script has been already compiled to Bytecode. Is this something unusual or is this just normal performance for Scala.

Comment: Have you built scala as cygwin program or is a windows binary ? If it is a windows binary, do you see the same delay outside of cygwin enviroment ? If you run a second time the program do you have the same delay ? If not it is likely the load time of DLL plus any antivirus checking.

Comment: It is a windows binary and the same delay is present when running the program outside of cygwin. If I run the program more than once it hardly makes any difference to the speed.

Comment: Have you timed an hello world in Java? Just to check if it is scala or just the jvm in general

Comment: Running a compiled hello world program in Java is about 10x times faster so I don't think it's the JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scala compiler is pretty slow but compiled application should work faster. On my `Ubuntu @ Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz` it takes:

```
mgosk@e7450:~$ time scalac hello.scala 

real    0m1.704s
user    0m4.772s
sys     0m0.120s

mgosk@e7450:~$ time scala hello.scala 
Hello, world!

real    0m0.563s
user    0m0.308s
sys     0m0.020s
```

Comment: I've found that Scala works fine for me as long as I'm using sbt so it's just the standard installation that doesn't seem to be functioning properly. Anyway, thanks for your help!